# Touchscreen Stopped Working After Restart

Tags: touchscreen

I'm having problem with my touch screen. The touch screen was working at first during trial and even after installation. Upon calibration, I restared my laptop and the touch screen feature is not working anymore.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and installed gnome session. My laptop is an old Toshiba SS 1700MY came from Japan with Intel Core 2 Solo.